# Custom library inherited form angular powered bootstrap

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I am working for an organization for which I need to create a custom control. Whereas I want to use Angular Powered Bootstrap. But I also need some modification over it like CSS, HTML template change even some functionality if possible.

I do not want to copy the Angular Powered Bootstrap and build over it because It is still in beta stage. If I do that then further changes which will be in that I will miss those.

I am looking for a way such as :

1. my custom library will have a dependency as "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "1.0.0"
2. I want to inherit the code whenever I need modification
3. This custom library will be used as dependencies where ever it is required.

In a nutshell, my question is: How to customized [angular powered bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/home).

Comment: If you control have styles or styleUrls, this override the others css

Comment: Why would you want to do this?  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Are the changes that you want to make something that could be of benefit to the original repo? If so, creating a fork of `ng-bootstrap`, making your changes and then committing those changes back to the community would help others as well. Short of that, I am not sure how well Angular handles components that inherit from other components. Example: [Something like this](https://scotch.io/tutorials/component-inheritance-in-angular-2) might be worth having a look at.